# The SQL Server proxy MUST be a domain account?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to setup a proxy account for a SQL Server 2000 instance (for running `xp_cmdshield`, by the way).  I have administrative privilegies on the local server, but not in the domain.  The [xp_sqlagent_proxy_account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260700%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) procedure expects the domain as a mandatory parameter.  I don't see any reason to require a domain account. I would like to use a local account. How I should I configure this to use a local account instead of a domain account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the local server's hostname as the domain. For example, if your server is named `server1` then use the account `server1\username`